# $(document).click(): does not fire alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Might be simple but I can find a reasonable explanation for that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function () {
        alert('ok');
    });
});
```

Does not fire the alert();
I am using the newest google chrome. Does browser put some restriction for that as there is in ajax callback functions?

**Edit 1:** Code is within `$(document).ready();`

Comment: Is your script surrounded by script tags and a document ready function?

Comment: see chrome javascript console for error

Comment: This works fine for me in both firefox and chrome.
You can always try calling this on the "body" instead.

Comment: Ajax? What Ajax? Also, create a fiddle / jsbin.

Comment: Try using strict mode, the code probably crashed before it reached the line you're addressing. The code is: use 'strict';

Comment: stupid question but have you included jQuery in your references? check the console output in the chrome debugger tool (F12 - default hotkey) for any errors. Also if you have some code running in an ajax callback, you should propably show the relevant code.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY9JM/) in your browser by clicking on result pane

Comment: Did you give reference to jquery plugin in your html code? (assuming external js file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to Encapsulate your code with

```
$(function(){
   //your code here 
});
```

**or**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just edit my post. Function is whitin $(document).ready();

Comment: That doesn't matter, `document` is always available (in fact, `$(document).ready` would fail as well if this was the solution).

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo why aren't you checking the console error? which was being shouted by other members for a while..

Comment: @pimvdb sorry I didn't get your explanation.

Comment: I mean that `$(document).ready` is **not** necessary for `$(document).click`. It's only required if you want to select elements as `$("selector")`.

Answer (score 1):

Strange but true, that's working on firefox but not on chrome. Try this one, works for me for latest version of chrome and firefox too:

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
     alert('ok');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$().ready(function() {   
    alert('ok');
});
```